# Overriding default Swig template filter for a single tag

Tags: javascript, swig-template

I need to inject a JavaScript object into an HTML script tag within a Swig template.

```
<script>
  var myObj = {{myObj|json_encode}};
</script>
```

The `json_encode` part works fine, but then the default HTML filter kicks in and I get this in my output:

```
<script>
  var myObj = {&quot;socketIOServerAddress&quot;:&quot;http://localhost:8989/&quot;}
</script>
```

How can I disable the default filter for this one tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was easier than expected.  For some reason, I am able to [chain another filter, `raw`, which disables the built-in filtering](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#filters-raw).  A little counter-intuitive, but it works.

```
<script>
  var myObj = {{myObj|json_encode|raw}};
</script>
```

Comment: But you don't need that !
json_encode is your own filter right ?
just make sure, you declared the filter function as "safe" and you don't need raw ...

e.g. my filter is named "attr" and uses the function "attrString":

    var attrString = function();
    attrString.safe = true;
    _swig.setFilter('attr', attrString);